# Application angular 6 can't access property "ngInjectableDef", depDefToken is undefined

Tags: angular

i'm facing this error and i have a problem when i navigate. The application is about ticket creation and displaying. The problem is when i try to display a ticket with a conversation and text editor, it's not displaying or when i go to somewhere else and return back and try to click on the ticket then it's displaying. But when i do an refresh with F5 and it returns to home with list of tickets then it's not displaying anymore and i have to the trick again. The text editor component is indicated maybe it's the problem. But it's occuring when i click for the first time on the link or just after refreshing.I don't know what is vendor.js in the browser error. When i remove conversation text-editor component the problem is not occuring anymore.

[image]

ConversationTextEditorComponent.html :

```
section class="text-editor-container" [class.hidden]="!conversation.isEditorOpen()">
    <reply-attachment-list [attachments]="conversation.draft.get().uploads" (detached)="conversation.draft.detachUpload($event)"></reply-attachment-list>

    <upload-progress-bar></upload-progress-bar>
    **ligne 5** <text-editor inlineUploadType="ticket" (onChange)="conversation.draft.setBody($event)" (onFileUpload)="conversation.draft.uploadFiles($event)" (onCtrlEnter)="submitReply()" #textEditor> 

        <div class="actions" customButtons *ngIf="currentUser.hasPermission('canned_replies.view')">
            <canned-replies-dropdown (onReplySelect)="applyCannedReply($event)"></canned-replies-dropdown>
        </div>

        <div class="actions last right" header>
            <button type="button" class="no-style editor-button save-draft-button" [class.success]="conversation.draft.get().id" (click)="saveDraftAndAddToReplies()" [matTooltip]="'Save Draft' | trans">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="check-circle"></mat-icon>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="no-style editor-button delete-draft-button" (click)="maybeDeleteDraft()" [matTooltip]="'Discard (Esc)' | trans"><mat-icon svgIcon="delete"></mat-icon></button>
        </div>
```

core.js :

```
*
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
var ERROR_DEBUG_CONTEXT = 'ngDebugContext';
var ERROR_ORIGINAL_ERROR = 'ngOriginalError';
var ERROR_LOGGER = 'ngErrorLogger';
function getDebugContext(error) {
    return error[ERROR_DEBUG_CONTEXT];
}
function getOriginalError(error) {
    return error[ERROR_ORIGINAL_ERROR];
}
function getErrorLogger(error) {
    return error[ERROR_LOGGER] || defaultErrorLogger;
}
function defaultErrorLogger(console) {
    var values = [];
    for (var _i = 1; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        values[_i - 1] = arguments[_i];
    }
  **ligne 1673**      console.error.apply(console, __spread(values));
    }
```

TextEditorComponent :

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewEncapsulation, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {TinymceTextEditor} from './editors/tinymce-text-editor.service';
import {HtmlTextEditor} from './editors/html-text-editor.service';
import {Settings} from '../core/config/settings.service';
import {OverlayPanel} from '../core/ui/overlay-panel/overlay-panel.service';
import {ColorpickerPanelComponent} from '../core/ui/color-picker/colorpicker-panel.component';
import { openUploadWindow } from '../uploads/utils/open-upload-window';
import { UploadQueueService } from '../uploads/upload-queue/upload-queue.service';
import { TextEditorImageValidator } from './validation/text-editor-image-validator';
import { UploadInputTypes } from '../uploads/upload-input-config';
import { CurrentUser } from '../auth/current-user';
import { BOTTOM_POSITION } from '../core/ui/overlay-panel/positions/bottom-position';
import {ucFirst} from '../core/utils/uc-first';

@Component({
    selector: 'text-editor',
    templateUrl: './text-editor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./text-editor.component.scss'],
    providers: [TinymceTextEditor, HtmlTextEditor],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    /**
     * TextArea element for visual text editor.
     */
    @ViewChild('visualArea') visualTextArea: ElementRef;

    /**
     * TextArea element for source text editor.
     */
    @ViewChild('sourceArea') sourceTextArea: ElementRef;

    /**
     * Model for editor source text area.
     */
    public sourceAreaModel: string;

    /**
     * Name of text editor that is currently active.
     */
    public activeEditor = 'visual';

    /**
     * Should advanced text editing controls be shown.
     */
    @Input() showAdvancedControls = false;

    /**
     * Whether only basic formatting options should be shown.
     */
    @Input() basic = false;

    /**
     * Minimum height for editor in pixels.
     */
    @Input() minHeight: number|string = 183;

    /**
     * Maximum height for editor in pixels. Contents will scroll after this height.
     */
    @Input() maxHeight = 530;

    /**
     * How to upload inline images.
     */
    @Input() inlineUploadType: string;

    /**
     * Fired when text editor contents change.
     */
    @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    /**
     * Fired when user uses ctrl+enter keybind while text editor is focused.
     */
    @Output() onCtrlEnter = new EventEmitter();

    /**
     * Fired when user selected files to upload from browser file upload dialog.
     */
    @Output() onFileUpload = new EventEmitter();

    /**
     * Text editor implementation instance.
     */
    private editor: any;

    /**
     * Create new TextEditor component instance.
     */
    constructor(
        private tinyMceEditor: TinymceTextEditor,
        private htmlEditor: HtmlTextEditor,
        public currentUser: CurrentUser,
        private uploadQueue: UploadQueueService,
        private settings: Settings,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        public el: ElementRef,
        private overlayPanel: OverlayPanel,
        private imageValidator: TextEditorImageValidator,
    ) {
        if (this.settings.get('text_editor_driver', 'TinymceTextEditor') === 'TinymceTextEditor') {
            this.editor = this.tinyMceEditor;
        } else {
            this.editor = this.htmlEditor;
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.bootTextEditor();
    }

   ...

    /**
     * Queries the current state for specified text editor command.
     * For example if the current selection is "bold".
     */
    public queryCommandState(name: string): boolean|number {
        return this.editor.queryCommandState(name);
    }

    /**
     * Execute specified tinymce command.
     */
    public execCommand(name: string, value: string|number = null) {
        this.editor.execCommand(name, value);
    }

    /**
     * Insert information container of specified type into the editor.
     */
    public insertInfoContainer(type: string) {
        // TODO: refactor into shortcodes maybe if need more of similar buttons in the future
        // TODO: translate once angular translation service is available
        this.insertContents(
            `<div class="widget widget-${type}"><div class="title">${ucFirst(type)}:</div><br></div>`
        );
    }

    .....

    /**
     * Show source text editor.
     */
    public showSourceEditor() {
        if ( ! this.editor.tinymceInstance.contentAreaContainer || this.activeEditor === 'source') return;

        this.activeEditor = 'source';

        this.renderer.setStyle(this.sourceTextArea.nativeElement, 'height', this.editor.tinymceInstance.contentAreaContainer.offsetHeight+'px');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.sourceTextArea.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.editor.tinymceInstance.contentAreaContainer, 'display', 'none');

        this.sourceAreaModel = this.editor.getContents({source_view: true});
    }

    /**
     * Open dropdown for attaching a file or uploading a new one.
     */
    public openFileUploadDialog() {
        openUploadWindow({multiple: true}).then(fileList => {
            this.onFileUpload.emit(fileList);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Open modal window for inserting inline image into editor.
     */
    public openInsertImageModal() {
        const params = {
            uri: 'uploads/images',
           // validator: this.imageValidator,
            httpParams: {type: this.inlineUploadType}
        };

        openUploadWindow({types: [UploadInputTypes.image]}).then(files => {
            this.uploadQueue.start(files, params).subscribe(fileEntry => {
                this.insertImage(this.settings.getBaseUrl(true) + fileEntry.url);
            });
        });
    }

   
    /**
     * Bootstrap active text editor implementation.
     */
    private bootTextEditor() {
        this.editor.setConfig({
            textAreaEl: this.visualTextArea,
            editorEl: this.el,
            minHeight: this.minHeight,
            maxHeight: this.maxHeight,
            onChange: this.onChange,
            onCtrlEnter: this.onCtrlEnter,
            showAdvancedControls: this.showAdvancedControls,
        });
    }
}
```

Further investigations before posting :
I had to remove ImageValidator in TextEditor for the bug to be removed but i want to keep it. But it was used one time in the file but i had to remove the declaration in the constructor for the bug to disapear.

private imageValidator: TextEditorImageValidator,

```
The file TextEditorImageValidator :

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UploadValidator } from '../../uploads/validation/upload-validator';
import { FileSizeValidation } from '../../uploads/validation/validations/file-size-validation';
import { convertToBytes } from '../../core/utils/convertToBytes';
import { FileTypeValidation } from '../../uploads/validation/validations/file-type-validation';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TextEditorImageValidator extends UploadValidator {
    protected readonly DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE_MB = 3;

    protected initValidations() {
        const validations = [
            new FileSizeValidation(
                {maxSize: convertToBytes(this.DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE_MB, 'MB')},
                this.i18n
            ),
            new FileTypeValidation({types: ['image']}, this.i18n),
        ];

        this.validations.push(...validations);
    }
}
```

So at the end , why just the declaration of TextEditroImageValidator is causing this bug. it seems to be an injection problem. Someone can help me ?
Thanks.

EDIT :

i think i've isolated the problem when i remove extends UploadValidator it works. UploadValidator is an abastract class in other folder (folder uploads). I think there is a problem with the import of the class :

```
import { Settings } from '../../core/config/settings.service';
import { Toast } from '../../core/ui/toast.service';
import { UploadValidation } from './validations/upload-validation';
import { UploadedFile } from '../uploaded-file';
import { Translations } from '../../core/translations/translations.service';

export abstract class UploadValidator {
    protected validations: UploadValidation[] = [];
    public showToast: boolean;

    constructor(
        protected settings: Settings,
        protected toast: Toast,
        protected i18n: Translations
    ) {}

    /**
     * Return true of file passes all validations.
     */
    public validate(file: UploadedFile): {failed: boolean, errorMessage?: string} {
        if ( ! this.validations.length) this.initValidations();

        const failed = this.validations.find(validation => {
            return validation.fails(file);
        });

        if (failed && this.showToast) {
            this.openErrorToast(failed.errorMessage);
        }

        return {failed: !!failed, errorMessage: failed ? failed.errorMessage : null};
    }

    /**
     * Validate file and show error message in toast.
     */
    public validateWithToast(file: UploadedFile) {
        const response = this.validate(file);
        this.openErrorToast(response.errorMessage);
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Show specified error message in toast.
     */
    protected openErrorToast(message: string) {
        this.toast.open(message);
    }

    /**
     * Can't init validators in constructor, because ngxs
     * store injects do not wait for angular APP_INITIALIZER
     */
    protected abstract initValidations();
}
```

Finally the problem doesn't occur when i don't use any core class from CoreModule in UploadValidator what is done wrong in the abstract class ??
It's not my code : code working :

```
//import { Settings } from '../../core/config/settings.service';
//import { Toast } from '../../core/ui/toast.service';
import { UploadValidation } from './validations/upload-validation';
import { UploadedFile } from '../uploaded-file';
//import { Translations } from '../../core/translations/translations.service';

export abstract class UploadValidator {
    protected validations: UploadValidation[] = [];
    public showToast: boolean;

    constructor(
       // protected settings: Settings,
        //protected toast: Toast,
       // protected i18n: Translations
    ) {}

    /**
     * Return true of file passes all validations.
     */
    public validate(file: UploadedFile): {failed: boolean, errorMessage?: string} {
        if ( ! this.validations.length) this.initValidations();

        const failed = this.validations.find(validation => {
            return validation.fails(file);
        });

        if (failed && this.showToast) {
            this.openErrorToast(failed.errorMessage);
        }

        return {failed: !!failed, errorMessage: failed ? failed.errorMessage : null};
    }

    /**
     * Validate file and show error message in toast.
     */
    public validateWithToast(file: UploadedFile) {
        const response = this.validate(file);
        this.openErrorToast(response.errorMessage);
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Show specified error message in toast.
     */
    protected openErrorToast(message: string) {
        //this.toast.open(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've come to a solution. So the problem was the use of an abstract class UploadValidator used in the component TextEditor. The imports wasn't sufficient for the abstract class to use the Services needed. So i modified UploadValidator like this.

```
import { Settings } from '../../core/config/settings.service';
import { Toast } from '../../core/ui/toast.service';
import { UploadValidation } from './validations/upload-validation';
import { UploadedFile } from '../uploaded-file';
import { Translations } from '../../core/translations/translations.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    deps: [
     Translations,
     Toast,
     Settings
    ],
  })
export abstract class UploadValidator {
    protected validations: UploadValidation[] = [];
    public showToast: boolean;

    constructor(
        protected settings: Settings,
        protected toast: Toast,
        protected i18n: Translations
    ) {}

    /**
     * Return true of file passes all validations.
     */
    public validate(file: UploadedFile): {failed: boolean, errorMessage?: string} {
        if ( ! this.validations.length) this.initValidations();

        const failed = this.validations.find(validation => {
            return validation.fails(file);
        });

        if (failed && this.showToast) {
            this.openErrorToast(failed.errorMessage);
        }

        return {failed: !!failed, errorMessage: failed ? failed.errorMessage : null};
    }

    /**
     * Validate file and show error message in toast.
     */
    public validateWithToast(file: UploadedFile) {
        const response = this.validate(file);
        this.openErrorToast(response.errorMessage);
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Show specified error message in toast.
     */
    protected openErrorToast(message: string) {
        this.toast.open(message);
    }

    /**
     * Can't init validators in constructor, because ngxs
     * store injects do not wait for angular APP_INITIALIZER
     */
    protected abstract initValidations();
}
```

So i've had Injectable to the class with services needed in deps section. It solved the problem.